# How to apply media query for iPads?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm optimizing my website across most popular devices using media queries in CSS file.
The problem the line below isn't working on iPads:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 415px) and (max-device-width: 768px) {
```

even though iPads comes with 768px width the CSS is all messed up. Interestingly, when I use mobile device simulator in dev tools everything looks fine.

Is there some gotchas I should be aware of ?

Comment: What version of which browser did you use on iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it so it is like this. Leave out device and just put min-width or max-width:

```
@media (min-width: 415px) and (max-width: 768px) { css here }
```

Comment: Will report back as soon as I have the iPad again. It's not with me atm.